# liked to know how repeating while loop in game works

Tags: loops, while-loop, lua, roblox

this code generates 100 chickens on a map within a certain area at the beginning of the game but one the player has collected all the 100 chickens there's none left to collect so id like to know how to re generate another 100 chickens say once the amount left has falling to 10 so the player will have a continuous amount of chicken to collect, hope this makes sense, thanks in advance. jp

```
local newChicken = game.ServerStorage:FindFirstChild("ChickenOnePart")

local TopLeftCorner = Vector3.new(-187.64, 20.679, 106.2)
local BottomRightCorner = Vector3.new(201.12, 20.679, -241.45)
local numberOfChickens = 100
local counter = 0

local singleTonRandom = Random.new(tick())

local function GetRandom(Min,Max)
return singleTonRandom:NextNumber(Min,Max)
end


while counter < numberOfChickens  do
local chicken = newChicken:Clone()
chicken.Anchored = true
chicken.Parent = game.Workspace
chicken.Name = "Chicken"
chicken.Position = Vector3.new(
    GetRandom(TopLeftCorner.X,BottomRightCorner.X),
    4,
    GetRandom(TopLeftCorner.Z,BottomRightCorner.Z)
)
counter = counter + 1

end
```

this code adds the counter up by 1 every time the player touches a chicken. Would i get the current chicken count from here?

```
if hitPart.Name == "Chicken" then
    event:FireServer(hitPart)
    local currentcount = playerGUI.ChickenGui.ChickenCounter.Text
    playerGUI.ChickenGui.ChickenCounter.Text = currentcount + 1
    hitPart:Destroy()
    debounce = true
    wait(0.1)
    debounce  = false
end
end)
```

and this codes for updating the leaderstas.

```
local event = Instance.new("RemoteEvent")
event.Name = "CurrencyAdd"
event.Parent = game.ReplicatedStorage

event.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr,part)
local currency = plr.leaderstats.Chickens
currency.Value = currency.Value + 1
end)


game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
local ls = Instance.new("Folder")
ls.Name = "leaderstats"
local m = Instance.new("IntValue",ls)
m.Name = "Chickens"
ls.Parent = plr

local cash = Instance.new("IntValue",ls)
cash.Name = "Cash"
end)
```

@Piglet thank you i sort of understand is this what you mean?

```
local newChicken = game.ServerStorage:FindFirstChild("ChickenOnePart")

local TopLeftCorner = Vector3.new(-187.64, 20.679, 106.2)
local BottomRightCorner = Vector3.new(201.12, 20.679, -241.45)
local numberOfChickens = 100
local counter = 0

local singleTonRandom = Random.new(tick())

local function GetRandom(Min,Max)
return singleTonRandom:NextNumber(Min,Max)
end

for counter = 1, numberOfChickens do
local chicken = newChicken:Clone()
chicken.Anchored = true
chicken.Parent = game.Workspace
chicken.Name = "Chicken"
chicken.Position = Vector3.new(
    GetRandom(TopLeftCorner.X,BottomRightCorner.X),
    4,
    GetRandom(TopLeftCorner.Z,BottomRightCorner.Z)
)
counter = counter + 1
end

function AddChicken(num)
for count = 10, num do
local chicken = newChicken:Clone()
chicken.Anchored = true
chicken.Parent = game.Workspace
chicken.Name = "Chicken"
chicken.Position = Vector3.new(
  GetRandom(TopLeftCorner.X,BottomRightCorner.X),
  4,
  GetRandom(TopLeftCorner.Z,BottomRightCorner.Z)
)
end        
end
AddChicken(90)
```

sorry about this i'm just only learning it all

Comment: Do you have any code that detects when a player touches a chicken yet?

Comment: hi, yes i have the code you mean, i added it to the op. Hope this helps. Regards jp

Comment: use a for loop instead of a while loop with a counter

Comment: hi @Piglet could you give me an example as i'm not 100% about the syntax used, i know its something like (for i = 1,10,1 do) but not sure where to put the code, soz

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just put that while loop in its own function, then call that function whenever the amount of chickens goes under a certain threshold, the same way GetRandom is called to put the chickens in position:

```lua
function GenerateChickens()
    while counter < numberOfChickens  do
        local chicken = newChicken:Clone()
        chicken.Anchored = true
        chicken.Parent = game.Workspace
        chicken.Name = "Chicken"
        chicken.Position = Vector3.new(
            GetRandom(TopLeftCorner.X,BottomRightCorner.X),
            4,
            GetRandom(TopLeftCorner.Z,BottomRightCorner.Z)
        )
        counter = counter + 1
    end
end
```

I don't know how you would get the current chicken count, but this should be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

As loops like this are very common there is a shorter form than:

```
local counter = 0
while counter < numberOfChickens do
  -- ...
  counter = counter + 1
end
```

This can be written using a numeric for loop

```
for counter = 1, numberOfChickens do
  -- ...
end
```

Adding another 100 chicken when there are only 10 left, as you suggested would give you 110 chicken. So you should add 90 if you want 100 chicken on the map.

To do that you should check the chicken count whenever a chicken is removed. As soon as your condition is true you should call a function that adds a certain number of chicken.

```
function AddChicken(num)
  for count = 1, num do
    local chicken = newChicken:Clone()
    chicken.Anchored = true
    chicken.Parent = game.Workspace
    chicken.Name = "Chicken"
    chicken.Position = Vector3.new(
      GetRandom(TopLeftCorner.X,BottomRightCorner.X),
      4,
      GetRandom(TopLeftCorner.Z,BottomRightCorner.Z)
    )
  end        
end
```

Just make sure the funcion is in newChicken's scope

Comment: hi, @Piglet  i'm not fully sure what you mean sorry about this, if you can show me how to write it i would really appreciate it if not then thank you for your help. jp

Comment: I think you're better off with doing a beginners tutorial and reading the Lua reference manual. If you do not understand the concept of functions or how to write a for loop there is no point in doing complex things like that moving code into a function so you can run it multiple times is as basic as it gets.